# Rearranging view controllers in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

OK so we have an interesting problem.

We have several view controllers, and we use the UINavigationController to manage the paths.  We have 2 paths to get to point E.

Path 1: A -> B -> E

Path 2: A -> B -> C -> D -> E

When you get to E, we remove C and D from the UINavigationController viewControllers array (essentially turn Path 2 into Path 1).  We do this by filtering out the view controllers for C and D.  Using NSLog I can verify that it appears to work.

On iOS 8+ everything works, but on iOS 7 hitting the back button will not go back to point B.  Also it does not crash the app.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it is pretty difficult to help you, but I can make a suggestion. Instead of relying on the UINavigation controller back button's default behavior you can try and implement an unwind segue on a custom back button.